# Unidirectional OneToMany with composite children key, not propagating parent id

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following 2 entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class ParentEntity{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dtvSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dtvSeq", sequenceName = "PARENT_ID_SEQ")
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "childEntityPk.parentId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Collection<ChildEntity> childrenEntities;

    //getters and setters ommited

}
```

And the children entity, with a composed primary key, partly referencing Parent_id (fk):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILDREN")
public class ChildEntity {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildEntityPk childEntityPk;

    //other fields
    //getter and setters ommited

    @Embeddable
    private class ChildEntityPk implements Serializable{
        long parentId;
        String name;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly to fetch data. However, if I want to persist a ParentEntity and its children entities in one go, I get an exception from Oracle.

This exception is thrown because hibernate did not update childEntity.childEntityPk.parentId and is trying to insert null.

I also played with @JoinColumn but without success.

I don't want to have a bi-directional mapping.

Comment: you do not need to go for `@EmbeddedId` anymore. you can simply annotate several fields with `@Id` which has the same effect, but erases things like `childEntityPk.parentId`. the solutions i see are either a bidirectional mapping which you don't want or you populate the child entities with the parent id's before you insert

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: just an oracle exception, because hibernate is trying to insert null in parent_id field of children table, which is not nullable

Comment: i write an answer, but i would complete it incrementally. So, please apply the changes which i suggest you in my answer, and let me know in comment, how it works. is it ok?

Comment: I can try give it a try yes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have addChild() method or just update the collection? I suggest

```
public void addChild(ChildEntity child) {
     child.setChildEntityPk(this.parentId, "name");
     childrenEntities.add(child);
}
```

Comment: yep this is one way to do it, but it looks like a little hack. I was hoping for a way to let hibernate doing it automatically.

Comment: @chouk That's not the hack. See the doc https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html